# allowing NSBundle.mainBundle() in swift iOS app to find "der" format certificate files

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, ssl, pinning

I am extremely new to Swift iOS programming in xcode. For whatever reason, my NSBundle.mainBundle() is able to find image files in the code base,

```
var path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle()
     .pathForResource("icon", ofType: "png")!)
```

returns a non-nil string.

However, I have a "DER" format public CA certificate in the same directory.

```
path = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle()
    .pathForResource("cacer", ofType: "der")!)
```

returns nil.

Any advice to give? Any extra information needed?

Comment: is your certificate files correctly referenced? like by dragging them to your project through xcode which it would automatically create its reference?

Comment: Consider adding screenshot of your file's Xcode's File Inspector utility to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `cancer.der` isn't referenced to app target.
Make sure that checkbox is on for that file:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thank you very very much for that info!